# Read content of div which contains input hidden jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a CakePHP project using jQuery and AJAX. I have a div which is repeated in a php loop.

This is what's the div look like:

```
<div class="heart">
 <input type="hidden" id="id of loop iterate" />
</div>
```

What I want is each time the div is clicked I get the id of the input hidden.

What I tried:

```
jQuery('.heart').click(function(){
            var input=$(this).html();
            alert(input.prop('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
$(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('id')
```

**Working Demo**

```js
jQuery('.heart').click(function() {
  var input = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('id')
  alert(input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heart">
  <input type="hidden" id="id of loop iterate" />Click Me !!!!!!!!!!
</div>
```

Comment: @Satpal I have updated my answer. Initially I was working on another method. But that was not good. I removed it now.

Comment: It will not work in case if there is more than input ?

Comment: I am not getting you. `It will not work in case if there is more than input ` means?

Comment: It means if there is more than one input ?

Comment: As per this code if there is more than one `hidden` input it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have see your code , your code come for dynamic for loop so , simple jquery not work, you want to little change in jquery , have a look here

```
     <script>
  $(document).on('click','.heart',function(){

           var input = $(this).children().attr('id');
           alert(input);

      });
   </script>
```

and your html code here , write some thing to find out div like that

```
 <div class="heart">
     gjdfjgdfsk
     <input type="hidden" id="id of loop iterate" />
</div>
```